# Central limit theorem on linear combination of activations in a neural network

Tags: central-limit-theorem, neural-networks

While I've read a paper, [Deterministic variational inference for robust bayesian neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.03958.pdf), I have some confusion parts.

On the contrary to a standard neural network framework, the author apply a activation function, followed by linear combination as follows.

$$(1) \quad \quad h^{(l)}=f(a^{(l-1)})$$
$$(2) \quad \quad a^{(l)} = h^{l}W^l+b^l$$

And the author claims that infinite linear combination of $h^l$ converges to Normal Distribution by Central Limit Theorem as below.

> $a^{(l)}$ is constructed by linear combination of many distinct
>   elements of $h'$, and in the limit of vanishing correlation between
>   terms in this combination, we can appeal to the central limit theorem
>   (CLT). Under the CLT, for a large enough hidden dimension and for
>   variational distributions with finite first and second moments,
>   elements $a_i$ will be normally distributed regardless of the
>   potentially complicated distribution for $h_j$ induced by $f$

I don't understand why CLT could be applied to linear combination of activations in this case.
Would anyone elaborate this one?